# Passing Serial Object Created by a Library to another Library

Tags: arduino, serial, esp32, library

I am trying to create a library for Topway brand LCD based on [this docs](https://www.topwaydisplay.com/sites/default/files/2020-06/Topway-Smart-LCD-SGTools-Handbook.pdf). Inspired by this library [header file](https://github.com/xreef/LoRa_E32_Series_Library/blob/master/LoRa_E32.h), and [source file](https://github.com/xreef/LoRa_E32_Series_Library/blob/master/LoRa_E32.cpp) I have created a Serial object in my library which is fix.h and fix.cpp. I've inspired that library because User can costimize hardware serial or software serial even can change this RX, TX pins. And this function works fine:

```
void fix::UART_SendChar(uint8_t ucDat) {
  this->serialDef.stream->write(ucDat); 

  while (!this->serialDef.stream->availableForWrite());
}
```

At this code I can create serial object and manuelly sending all datas. After that topway company send me a api header and source file . there so many ready function on it. like this:

```
#include "hmtapi.h"         // 中间件函数头文件
//#include "UartDriver.h"  // 硬件驱动层头文件 
    


/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  __SendByte
** 函数功能:  单字节发送函数
** 输入参数:  ucData：        数据
** 返 回 值:  无
*********************************************************************************************************/
void __SendByte(INT8U ucData)
{
    //UART_SendChar(ucData);                          // 根据不同的芯片配置
}


/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  __SendDByte
** 函数功能:  双字节发送函数
** 输入参数:  usData：  数据
** 返 回 值:  无
*********************************************************************************************************/
void __SendDByte(INT16U usData)
{
    __SendByte((usData >> 8) & 0xFF);                 // 发送高8位数据
    __SendByte(usData & 0xFF);                        // 发送低8位数据
}


/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  __SendByteStr
** 函数功能:  单字节字符串发送函数
** 输入参数:  *pucStr:        要发送的命令字符串指针
**        ulNum:    要发送的数据个数
** 返 回 值:  无
*********************************************************************************************************/
void __SendByteStr(INT8U const *pucStr, INT32U ulNum)
{
    INT32U i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < ulNum; i++)                        // 发送指定字节数据
    {    
        __SendByte(pucStr[i]);
    }
}


/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  __SendHead
** 函数功能:  发送命令帧头
** 输入参数:  无
** 输出参数:  无
** 返 回 值:  无
*********************************************************************************************************/
void __SendHead(void)
{
    __SendByteStr(__GucFrameHead, 1);

}


/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  __SendTail
** 函数功能:  发送命令帧尾
** 输入参数:  无
** 输出参数:  无
** 返 回 值:  无
*********************************************************************************************************/
void __SendTail(void)
{
    __SendByteStr(__GucFrameTail, 4);
}

/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  __SendSpecialFuncCode
** 函数功能:  发送特殊功能指令
** 输入参数:  无
** 输出参数:  无
** 返 回 值:  无
*********************************************************************************************************/
void __SendSpecialFuncCode(void)
{
    __SendByteStr(__GucFrameSpecialFuc, QUANTITYOF_ARRAY_MEMBER(__GucFrameSpecialFuc));  // 发送特殊功能指令
}
/****************************** 串口显示终端应用层函数 **************************************************/

/****************************************************************************
* 名    称： HMT_HandShake() 
* 功    能： 发送握手指令  0x30
* 入口参数： 无       
* 出口参数： 无
****************************************************************************/
void HMT_HandShake(void)
{
    __SendHead();                          // 发送帧头
    __SendByte(0x30);                      // 发送命令
    __SendTail();                          // 发送帧尾
}


/****************************************************************************
* 名    称： HMT_SendCMD_ReadVersion 
* 功    能： 发送 读取版本信息的指令  0x31
* 入口参数： 无       
* 出口参数： 无
****************************************************************************/
void HMT_SendCMD_ReadVersion(void)
{
    __SendHead();                          // 发送帧头
    __SendByte(0x31);                      // 发送命令
    __SendTail();                          // 发送帧尾
}
```

Also header file is:

```
#ifndef _HMT_H_
#define _HMT_H_

/*********************************************************************************************************
  需要引入的头文件
*********************************************************************************************************/
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MCU_TYPE STM32

/*********************************************************************************************************
  定义与编译器无关的数据类型
*********************************************************************************************************/
typedef unsigned char  BOOLEAN;                                         /* 布尔变量                     */
typedef unsigned char  INT8U;                                           /* 无符号8位整型变量            */
typedef signed   char  INT8S;                                           /* 有符号8位整型变量            */
typedef unsigned short INT16U;                                          /* 无符号16位整型变量           */
typedef signed   short INT16S;                                          /* 有符号16位整型变量           */
typedef unsigned long  INT32U;                                          /* 无符号32位整型变量           */
typedef signed   long  INT32S;                                          /* 有符号32位整型变量           */
typedef float          FP32;                                            /* 单精度浮点数（32位长度）     */
typedef double         FP64;                                            /* 双精度浮点数（64位长度）     */
//typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;

typedef unsigned long  uint32;                                          /* 无符号32位整型变量           */
typedef signed   long  int32s;                                          /* 有符号32位整型变量           */
typedef unsigned short uint16;                                          /* 无符号16位整型变量           */
typedef unsigned char  uint8;                                           /* 无符号8位整型变量            */
 

/*********************************************************************************************************
  显示终端坐标定义
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define  HMT_XADDR_MAX       800                                        /* 液晶X轴坐标最大值            */
#define  HMT_YADDR_MAX       480                                        /* 液晶Y轴坐标最大值            */

/*********************************************************************************************************
  内存中图片序号最大值
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define  PAGE_ID_MAX         999                                        /* 图片序号最大值           */
#define  ICON_ID_MAX         999                                                          /* ICON图片序号最大值        */
/*********************************************************************************************************
  背光定义
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define  LIGHT_TIME_MAX      256                                        /* 背光时间最大值               */
#define  LIGHT_PWMLEVEL_MAX  0x3F                                       /* 背光时间最大值               */

/*********************************************************************************************************
  蜂鸣器定义
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define  BEEP_LEVEL_MAX      0x3F                                       /* 蜂鸣器等级最大值               */

/*********************************************************************************************************
  其他最大值定义
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define  CMD_HEAD             0xAA
#define  CMD_TAIL             0xCC, 0x33, 0xC3, 0x3C
#define  CMD_SPECIALFUNC      0x55, 0xAA, 0x5A, 0xA5 
#define  PROJECT_MAX          9                                    
#define  BUZZERFRE_MAX        0x32                                   
#define  SETElEMENTTYPE_MAX   1                                       
#define  STRID_MAX            127         
#define  STR_LENGTH_MAX       128  
#define  NUMID_MAX            119                                                                                                                                                  

/*********************************************************************************************************
  显示终端颜色宏定义
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define  BLACK               0x0000                                     /* 黑色：    0,   0,   0        */
#define  NAVY                0x000F                                     /* 深蓝色：  0,   0, 128        */
#define  DGREEN              0x03E0                                     /* 深绿色：  0, 128,   0        */
#define  DCYAN               0x03EF                                     /* 深青色：  0, 128, 128        */
#define  MAROON              0x7800                                     /* 深红色：  128,  0,  0        */
#define  PURPLE              0x780F                                     /* 紫色：    128,  0,128        */
#define  OLIVE               0x7BE0                                     /* 橄榄绿：  128,128,  0        */
#define  LGRAY               0xC618                                     /* 灰白色：  192,192,192        */
#define  DGRAY               0x7BEF                                     /* 深灰色：  128,128,128        */
#define  BLUE                0x001F                                     /* 蓝色：    0,    0,255        */
#define  GREEN               0x07E0                                     /* 绿色：    0,  255,  0        */
#define  CYAN                0x07FF                                     /* 青色：    0,  255,255        */
#define  RED                 0xF800                                     /* 红色：    255,   0, 0        */
#define  MAGENTA             0xF81F                                     /* 品红：    255,   0,255       */
#define  YELLOW              0xFFE0                                     /* 黄色：    255, 255, 0        */
#define  WHITE               0xFFFF                                     /* 白色：    255, 255,255       */

/*********************************************************************************************************
  显示终端字符显示类型
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define  GBK2132_24x24       0                                         /* 24x24 GBK2132内码            */
#define  GBK2132_48x48       1                                         /* 48x48 GBK2132内码            */
#define  NUMBER_120x200      2                                         /* 120x200 0~9数字              */
#define  ASC_6x8             3                                         /* 6x8 ASCII字符                */
#define  ASC_8x8             4                                         /* 8x8 ASCII字符                */
#define  ASC_8x16            5                                         /* 8x16 ASCII字符                */
#define  ASC_ISO_10x16       6                                         /* 10x16 ASCII字符               */
#define  ASC_ISO_BOLD_10x16  7                                         /* 10x16 ASCII字符 ISO+Bold      */
#define  ASC_ISO_17x24       8                                         /* 17x24 ASCII字符               */
#define  ASC_ISO_BOLD_15x24  9                                         /* 15x24 ASCII字符 ISO+Bold      */
#define  ASC_COMIC_17x24    10                                         /* 17x24 ASCII字符  Bold         */
#define  ASC_ISO_20x32      11                                         /* 20x32 ASCII字符  ISO          */
#define  ASC_ISO_BOLD_20x32 12                                         /* 20x32 ASCII字符 ISO+Bold      */
#define  NUMBER_47x48       13                                         /* 47x48 0~9数字  '+','-',':'    */
#define  NUMBER_63x64       14                                         /* 63x64 0~9数字  '+','-',':'    */
#define  NUMBER_79x80       15                                         /* 79x80 0~9数字  '+','-',':'    */

/*********************************************************************************************************
其他宏定义
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define SET_BAUD1200    0x00
#define SET_BAUD2400    0x01
#define SET_BAUD4800    0x02
#define SET_BAUD9600    0x03
#define SET_BAUD19200   0x04
#define SET_BAUD38400   0x05
#define SET_BAUD57600   0x06
#define SET_BAUD115200  0x07
#define SET_NONE_RESPONSE             0x00   
#define SET_PRESS_RESPONSE_POSITION   0x81
#define SET_RELEASE_RESPONSE_POSITION 0x82
#define SET_RESPONSE_KEYID            0x83
#define MAX_NUMARRAY_SIZE             40  
#define VERSION_LENGTH                5  
#define TOPWAY_CONNECT_OK             "Topway HMT Ready"  
#define ELEMENTTYPE_STR               0x00
#define ELEMENTTYPE_NUM               0x01
#define REFRESH_ON                    0x01
#define REFRESH_OFF                   0x00
#define VP_N16                        0x08
#define VP_N32                        0x02
#define VP_N64                        0x03
#define VP_STR                        0x00
#define FALSE                         0
#define TRUE                          1
#define TIMER_INCREASE                0x03 
#define TIMER_REDUSE                  0x01
#define TIMER_TRUN_OFF                0x00
#define BEEP_CTRL_LOOPCOUNT_1         0x01
#define BEEP_CTRL_TIME1_100MS         1
#define BEEP_CTRL_TIME2_0MS           0
#define BEEP_CTRL_FRE1_5KHZ           50
#define BEEP_CTRL_FRE2_0HZ            0

#define QUANTITYOF_ARRAY_MEMBER(ARRAY) sizeof(ARRAY)/sizeof(ARRAY[0]) 

/******************************************************************************************************
* 名    称： HMT_HandShake()
* 功    能： 发送握手指令 0x30
* 入口参数： 无      
* 出口参数： 无
******************************************************************************************************/
extern void HMT_HandShake(void);


/****************************************************************************
* 名    称： HMT_SendCMD_ReadVersion() 
* 功    能： 发送读取版本信息的指令   0x31
* 入口参数： 无      
* 出口参数： 无
****************************************************************************/
extern void HMT_SendCMD_ReadVersion(void);
/****************************************************************************
* 名    称： HMT_SendCMD_ReadPageID() 
* 功    能： 发送 读页面ID号的指令   0x32
* 入口参数： 无      
* 出口参数： 无
****************************************************************************/
extern void HMT_SendCMD_ReadPageID(void);

/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  HMT_SetSystemConfig
** 函数功能:  配置波特率以及触摸返回动作0xe0
** 输入参数:   usBaudrate:串口波特率：0x00~0x07对应波特率从1200-115200bps
** usTouchmode:触摸返回动作
** 输出参数:  无
** 返 回 值:  正确返回TRUE，否则返回FALSE
*********************************************************************************************************/
extern BOOLEAN HMT_SystemConfig(INT8U usBaudrate, INT8U usTouchAction);


/*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  HMT_SelectProject
** 函数功能:  多工程时，用于切换工程0xe1
** 输入参数:   projectID:工程ID   
** 输出参数:  无
** 返 回 值:  正确返回TRUE，否则返回FALSE
*********************************************************************************************************/
extern BOOLEAN HMT_SelectProject(INT8U projectID);


/*
 * 触摸屏操作
 */
 /*********************************************************************************************************
** 函数名称:  HMT_TouchCalibration
** 函数功能:  触摸屏校准(注意只有第一次使用触摸屏时需要校准) 0XE4
** 输入参数:  无
** 输出参数:  无
** 返 回 值:  无
*********************************************************************************************************/
extern void HMT_TouchCalibration (void);
```

libraries are very long I have only paste a limited area.

**The point is,** hmt api files are perfect but

```
void __SendByte(INT8U ucData)
{
    //UART_SendChar(ucData);                          // 根据不同的芯片配置
}
```

at this function `UART_SendChar(ucData);` was writen for STM32 with keil. So I cant use this ready to use library. instead of `UART_SendChar(ucData);` how can I call this function where in created by fix.cpp

```
void fix::UART_SendChar(uint8_t ucDat) {
  this->serialDef.stream->write(ucDat);  // Seri porttan veri gönderme

  while (!this->serialDef.stream->availableForWrite())
    ;  // Verinin gönderildiğinden emin olmak için bekleyin
}
```

as a result there will be 4 files, fix.h, fix.cpp and hmt_api.h, hmt_api.cpp

Comment: It looks like this has nothing to do with Arduino, serial, esp32 or library even. You are dealing with generic non-electronics programming question, which mostly seems to be about how to combine C and C++? I mean, why can you not create a C callable function which the original library calls anyway, and in there call your C++ write method for the instance of your actual serial object?

Comment: original library mean, hmt api i think.  Maybe even if I move the functions in the hmt api to the fix library. but I was wondering if we can get a solution by moving the seril object. because it makes very easy for me

Comment: You can do anything you want to the files you have. But is that an electrical engineering question?

Comment: I dont know. where should be i have to carry